Pure instrumental recording of Bach's St Matthew Passion
For me, Bach's St Matthew Passion is easily the greatest work of music I know. However, the more I listen to it, the more problems I have with its text.
It's not just the fact that it's a deeply religious text which clearly is from a century that is quite a bit in the past. When I ask religious people I know about some passages of the text, they mostly respond with "Well, don't take it too literally, this is hundreds of years old". So even people with a religious background have their issues with the text.
What's more, I know enough people who quite like Classical Music, but do not like Classical singing.
That said, I keep wondering whether it wouldn't be possible to play this work purely instrumental, to bring forward its pure beauty, and make it available to a larger audience:

In the chorales, the two choirs could be replaced by a Baroque Chamber Music ensemble, or by a few Woodwind instruments.
In the arias, the singer's voices could be played by violins or maybe transverse flutes.
The recitatives, I would just not record them.

Of course, this would need some detail work for each aria, to find out how the character of the voices can be expressed best.
Is there such a recording? I couldn't find anything, neither on Spotify nor on Google.

As intriguing as this is, voting to close for a few reasons. 1) "help me find a __" questions are not covered here, and 2) Stack Exchange is built around, not abstract discussion, but solving concrete, objective problems, so "wouldn't it be cool if ___" questions aren't well suited. See more about focusing questions here. Meanwhile, everything is fair game in the chat room.

@AndyBonner thanks, no problem if you vote to close, I expected this more or less, and was hoping that I get a satisfying answer before it's closed :-)

Since this question is off topic, rather than providing an answer here, I put it in the main Music chat room: The Practice Room.  Enjoy.   @AndyBonner


I keep wondering whether it wouldn't be possible to play this work purely instrumental ...

Of course it would

... to bring forward its pure beauty

Vocal music is all about the text, or at least good vocal music is, and this is of course very high on any list of the best vocal music.  Removing the text is tantamount to taking the music out of context, not a means of achieving "pure beauty."
Consider for example the famous collection of 4-voice chorales, without words.  This gives people the impression that Bach chose entirely arbitrarily, on some occasion, to use a diminished seventh chord on a certain note of the melody while on another he might have used a plain triad on the same note of the same melody.  But if you see the texts of the different settings of the chorale, you'll see that the diminished seventh chord sets a word such "cross," "death," "sin," "wounds," or similar.  The text is an integral part of the music.
To clarify, I am not saying that nobody should ever do this, but rather that someone who does ought to be conscious of -- and sensitive to -- the fact that they are removing a central part of the work from their performance of it.
Of course, texts can be problematic for any of a number of reasons, especially if they are nearly 2000 years old (as the most controversial parts of this piece are).
You can probably find some individual movements recorded without singers, but I doubt very highly that anyone has done this for the entire work.  The approach that would be most consistent with historical practice would probably be to replace the sopranos with cornetto and other parts with trombones, alto for alto, tenor for tenor, and bass for bass.  This was a common practice from the Renaissance through the Romantic period, one that Bach himself used from time to time in his cantatas, and one that works particularly well because of the similarity between these instruments and human voices.

Thank you. However, I wasn't asking about an approach that would be "most consistent with historical practice". Let's take the Goldberg Variations. I guess many people familiar with them would argue that they are all about the piano, that you cannot play them on any other instrument without taking the music out of context. And there we are, Rachlin/Imai/Maisky have done a wonderful rendering of the Goldberg Variations for a String trio. As much as I love them on piano, some of the variations on Strings actually sound as if they were written that way. At least to me ‍♂️

@Bass Bach wrote the Goldberg Variations to be played on a two-manual harpsichord, so playing them on the piano is already talking them significantly out of context.  It's perfectly valid to do it, but it's better to be aware.  If I were performing the Passion without singers, I'd use the trombones not particularly because it's historical but because I think it would work best.  But sure, for some of the solos especially, other instruments would work as well and maybe even better. Changing the instrument used for instrumental music, though, is a less drastic change than abandoning the text.

@Bass another thought: I say "perfectly valid" in mind of the fact that Bach himself did this sort of thing all the time, though not as drastically as replacing an entire choir with instruments. One of the more drastic examples is the solo violin partita adapted for orchestra and solo organ. There are also several examples of choral movements that he reused for different texts, though he always adapted the music to the new text, underscoring the point about the importance of text to vocal music. He even adapted other composers' music (e.g. Pergolesi). It's standard practice for the time.

@Bass in further news, my wife chose a concert for us to attend with some friends tomorrow night ... of the Goldberg Variations played by a string quartet.  I'll let you know how it is :-)

@Bass I was wondering, when you said "like Classical Music, but do not like Classical singing," whether that's actually a reaction to a Bel Canto "operatic" style that would have been the norm even a few decades ago. I wonder whether, by sampling a number of more recent "early music" performances, you might find the singing closer to modern "non-classical" styles. Don't get me wrong; most early music singers still use a diction and projection that make the untrained say "Aw hell, that's opera!", but we don't have quite as much bellowing and maniacal vibrato these days.

@phoog I was fascinated by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goldberg_Variations_(Uri_Caine_album) in college

@phoog wow! Never had the chance to listen to that live. But I think my Spotify history will confirm that I have listened to stringy Goldberg at least as many times as to keyed Goldberg. Yes, replacing Choirs is a more drastic experiment. Still pretty sure that St Matthew Passion would make a wonderful instrumental "suite" if done right.

@AndyBonner I'll have to give that a listen.  I was (long out of college and) living upstairs from one of your thesis advisors when it was recorded.

@AndyBonner yes, the St Matthew Passion recordings I listen to are mostly done with original Baroque instruments as much as possible, and the singers don't use vibrato that much. But I think most of my friends would still say "that's opera singing", and I can't blame them. My biggest problem is the "Jesus" bass. There is always this beautiful instrumental "halo" as soon as Jesus speaks. But I have not yet found one single recording where the singer sings in a way that I perceive as "natural". I cannot hear the exact tones, there is always something like a vibrato that varies the tone a bit.

To me, this mostly just sounds wrong, as if the singer were not able to hit the notes in an exact way. I know, they are professionals and I'm not, but I just have to say that this diminishes the "fun" hearing St Matthew Passion pretty much. And then there is the text.. "Ihr habet allezeit Armen bei euch, mich aber habt ihr nicht allezeit." - yeah sure. I know, Bach just took that from the Bible, but I'd rather not hear it every time I listen to it..

@Bass well, context again, the gospel text -- the parts sung by the evangelist and Jesus (and the chorus when it portrays the crowd) --  is actually the critical part of the piece.  Bach didn't "take it from the bible"; he composed the arias and other choruses as add-ons to the prescribed gospel reading for the day.  Their purpose is to comment on that gospel.  The dramatic connections between the gospel and the commentary pieces is something else you'd lose by doing this.  But I'm sure I've heard a good Jesus without too much vibrato; I'll see if I can come up with some suggestions.

@phoog that would be nice, thank you. Regarding the gospel, yes, Bach "took the text from the Bible", meaning he didn't invent all these problematic text parts himself. I know that Bach composed it for that "purpose". And yes, I'd lose the dramatic connections, I can see that. However, I would gain music that's free from any ideological entanglement. Imagine a composer who has worked for an evil dictator or some other problematic customer. I'm sure people would regard this music as "part of the evil ideology" and do all sorts of things to remove the ideology from the music.

@phoog just to illustrate my point: https://open.spotify.com/album/5ZHCqltda5ywYkHPqFIUQJ if you listen to part 11 at 0:14 and at 0:41-0:47. Although in most cases, the singer does not use vibrato, in these particular instances there is something that I perceive very much as "Opera singing". Moreover, they are sung in a way as if Jesus was reproachful or vengeful against Judas. I'm not a religious person, but I think if there is one practical thing we can learn from Jesus of Nazareth, it is that vengeance is not a good thing. There are many more examples which make listening difficult for me.
